# In what order are Java constraints being executed

Tags: java, validation, constraints

I have a Java method in which the method itself is annotated with a constraint (cross-parameter) and the arguments are also annotated with constraints (@NotNull, @NotEmpty etc).
Is the method constraint validated after method argument validation or is the order of validation not specified?

Answer (score 2):

Annotations don't inherently do anything. They just mark things. `javac` itself knows what `@Deprecated` and `@Override` and `@FunctionalInterface` mean, but the effects are always to either do nothing, or to generate a compiler error: These annotations do not cause the compiler to generate any code.

Aside from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) this is a general principle of annotations, and even Project Lombok is an annotation processor: You have to put lombok on your classpath during a compilation, or nothing happens.

In other words, **it is not possible** for the `@NonNull` annotation in your code to generate any null check all on its own. The constraints are applied elsewhere, or by a code generating annotation processor that you explicitly include by putting it on the classpath or passing it along as annotation processor. For example, it *IS* possible for code you invoke to introspect your method and notice things. Thus, you could for example have:

```
class Example {
    @NotEmpty String name;
}
```

and then you can do:

```
new Example("");
```

and this won't cause an exception. But you could do:

```
Validator validator = SomeHypotheticalValidationLibrary.newValidator();
validator.validate(new Example(""));
```

and then this validator would produce an error stating that the instance you provided fails verification. This is an example of annotations being introspected.

And now to answer your question:

The order in which such constraints are validated depends entirely on the validation library you use to do the validation; out of the box, the annotation itself does not and cannot produce any validation code. You'd have to check the documentation of your validation library, and provide the context within which you are validating.

If you're talking specifically about lombok's [@NonNull](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) - lombok scans your code for null checks (either of the form `if (x == null) throw new Something();` or of the form `Objects.nullCheck` or guava's nullcheck). If it finds a nullcheck for an `@NonNull` annotated parameter, lombok does nothing. If it doesn't, it generates a nullcheck after all your explicit null checks. Lombok stops scanning for nullchecks once it hits a line that is NOT a nullcheck (so, neither an `if (x == null)` nor a `methodInvocation(x, "optional text");`). `@NonNull` is currently the only annotation that causes lombok to generate validation code (there is no `@lombok.NotEmpty`).

We may be able to give more insights if you explain which annotation processors / validation frameworks you are using.

Comment: Do some IDEs automatically do some validation checks based on the presence of annotations such as `@NonNull` and `@NotEmpty`?

Comment: @Basil Bourque not really; the only one that is somewhat commonly used is `@NonNull` and related annotations, but these are compile time checks, similar to generics. They don't generate any runtime code. Validation and compile time consistency checks are in many ways polar opposites: Validation implies runtime checks. compile time consistency checking implies a system whereby no runtime checks are required (and in fact flagged as superfluous, dead code).